# Wrong IP address in docker swarm service

Tags: docker, networking, devops, swarm

I have very weird problem:

I have the swarm cluster and one of my service have wrong ip:

```
$ docker service inspect nginx_backend | grep Addr
                    "Addr": "10.0.0.107/24"
```

From any container in the cluster:

```
/ # ping nginx_backend
PING nginx_backend (10.0.0.107): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.107: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.107: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.107: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.107: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms
^C
--- nginx_backend ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.057/0.066/0.083 ms
```

But in the server which hosted `nginx_backend` container:

```
root@backend:~# docker inspect nginx_backend.1.myzy10psfdl9r4jljrsz5zd5t | grep IPv4
                        "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.87"
```

And when some service try connect by name it got connect error, but if I manually put record like `10.0.0.87 nginx_backend` to `/etc/hosts` inside a container, it have successful connect.

What I did wrong?)

Answer (score 5):

Docker creates (by default) a Virtual IP (VIP) for each service. That's the `10.0.0.107`. It then balances requests between the backend containers. In the second example (`10.0.0.87`) you're seeing the IP address of one of the containers. That's routable within Docker as well (which is why hitting the IP works). However the name (`nginx_backend.1.myzy10psfdl9r4jljrsz5zd5t`) is not DNS resolvable so that's why that fails.

You can find a list of the 'backing' containers for a service by doing a DNS lookup on `tasks.nginx_backend.`

Some more background here: https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, you right, I forget about it. But I've tried connect from another service by DNS resolvable name like `nginx_backend` as it name (at least other service see each other with service name). But this service don't answer. I think it may another problem instead of I wrote. But may be you know where to I have to see?)

Comment: @Kealman, probably you meat issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30487 which was fixed in release 18.06