# Resolving hostname inside a container docker deploy with swarm

Tags: docker, swarm, mysql-group-replication

I deploy some service with swarm. When I ping the service label inside the corresponding container, it gives an IP not present in ifconfig.

In my /etc/hosts I have only automatic names generates by docker. In swarm, I can't use 'name' option in docker-compose.

I try to configure mysql group replication and it verify that the node name matches an ip of the node container.

I find a lot of post about this but I didn't find a clearly a way to do.

Could you help me ?

Comment: The fact that pinging a service label inside a container gives an IP that isn't in ifconfig might be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590866/wrong-ip-address-in-docker-swarm-service.